# JS: How to make an XMLHttpRequest on Wikidata?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, json, wikidata

**Given data such:**

```
http://wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&sites=frwiki&titles=Japan&languages=es&props=descriptions&format=json
```

**How to make a valid JS / JQuery XML HttpRequest ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Fiddle with 3 working solutions](http://jsfiddle.net/HNPyc/98/)** in action.

**Given an external JSON:**

```
myurl = 'http://wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&sites=frwiki&titles=France&languages=zh-hans|zh-hant|fr&props=sitelinks|labels|aliases|descriptions&format=json'
```

**Solution 1: $.ajax() + jsonp:**

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "jsonp",
  url: myurl ,
  }).done(function ( data ) {
  // do my stuff
});
```

**Solution 2: $.ajax()+json+&calback=?:**

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: myurl + '&callback=?',
  }).done(function ( data ) {
  // do my stuff
});
```

**Solution 3: $.getJSON()+calback=?:**

```
$.getJSON( myurl + '&callback=?', function(data) {
  // do my stuff
});
```

Documentations: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ , http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/